# Trapping Session_End in vb.net 2012

Tags: jquery, asp.net, .net, vb.net, visual-studio-2012

I'm using Visual Studio 2012 (VB), JQuery 1.8.2, Javascript 1.5, windows server 2008 R2

I need a way to guarantee that "some things" happen at the end of a user session. 
- sending email to customers, telling them what they did during the session

It seems so clear that many other web developers would have "stuff" they NEED to make SURE happens at the end of a user session!!

The 1st place I thought of was Session_End (doh). But Session_End seems dependent on the timeout in web.config or calling Session_Abandon, and I've had cases where they didn't work..

Though I have a logout button, people will OFTEN not use it, and just close the browser.

I've spent TOO much time trying to implement "trap browser close" logic with onbeforeunload.. (trap/log postback events and in onbeforeunload, check the log - if the event means they're leaving the site, call Session_Abandon, etc..)

Has anyone solved this? and if not, why? I can't be the first person to need it..

Comment: Why doesn't Session_End work for you? Why don't you just set a timeout in web.config?

Comment: In addition to sending email, I need to disconnect a unc connection established during the session.. I don't want to rely on Session_End to have the connection open longer than I have to..  (and thanks for the VERY fast reply!)

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you should have the client poll the server every few seconds via AJAX. If a certain amount of time goes by and the client hasn't checked in, then the server can do cleanup.

Comment: I saw a similar project [here](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/VBASPNETDetectBrowserCloser-f501cffe/view/SourceCode) (though I don't think it used AJAX) It seems like a custom session timeout. That would be better than an arbitrary one. I think I'm just surprised we don't have an established way to KNOW the browser is done with our site.. Thanks!

Comment: The web is [stateless](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stateless_protocol) by design.

Answer (score 0):

Session_end doesn't scale if you ever need to change from in-process session state (which doesn't scale) to SQL Server session state.  msm8bball has a good suggestion, though I'd set the polling at no less than one minute.  You will have to account for the fact that unless your design prohibits it, the same user may have more than one session open at the same time.